# Find the limit of the following product series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinitesimals

I am trying to find the limit of the following :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1- \frac{ 2}{3}\right)^\frac{3}{n} \left(1- \frac{ 2}{4}\right)^\frac{4}{n} \left(1- \frac{ 2}{5}\right)^\frac{5}{n}...\left(1- \frac{ 2}{n+2}\right)^\frac{n+2}{n}  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_n
=(1- \frac{ 2}{3})^\frac{3}{n}(1- \frac{ 2}{4})^\frac{4}{n}(1- \frac{ 2}{5})^\frac{5}{n}...(1- \frac{ 2}{n+2})^\frac{n+2}{n}
=\prod_{k=3}^{n+2} (1-\frac{2}{k})^{k/n}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
b_n
&= \ln a_n\\
&= \sum_{k=3}^{n+2} \frac{k}{n}\ln(1-\frac{2}{k})\\
&= \frac1{n}\sum_{k=3}^{n+2} k\ln(\frac{k-2}{k})\\
&= \frac1{n}\sum_{k=3}^{n+2} k(\ln(k-2)-\ln(k))\\
&= \frac1{n}\left(\sum_{k=3}^{n+2} k\ln(k-2)-\sum_{k=3}^{n+2} k\ln(k)\right)\\
&= \frac1{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k+2)\ln(k)-\sum_{k=3}^{n+2} k\ln(k)\right)\\
&= \frac1{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\ln(k)+\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2\ln(k)-\sum_{k=3}^{n+2} k\ln(k)\right)\\
&= \frac1{n}\left(1\ln(1)+2\ln(2)+2\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln(k)-(n+1)\ln(n+1)-(n+2)\ln(n+2)\right)\\
&= \frac1{n}\left(2\ln(2)+2\ln(n!)-(n+1)\ln(n+1)-(n+2)\ln(n+2)\right)\\
&= \frac1{n}\left(2\ln(2)+2(n\ln(n)-n+O(\ln(n))-n(\ln(n+1)+\ln(n+2))-(\ln(n+1)+2\ln(n+2))\right)\\
&= 2\ln(n)-(\ln(n+1)+\ln(n+2))-2+O(\ln(n)/n)-(\ln(n+1)+2\ln(n+2))\\
&= \ln(n^2/((n+1)(n+2))-2+O(\ln(n)/n)\\
&= -\ln((n+1)(n+2)/n^2)-2+O(\ln(n)/n)\\
&= -\ln((n^2+3n+2)/n^2)-2+O(\ln(n)/n)\\
&= -\ln(1+3/n+2/n^2)-2+O(\ln(n)/n)\\
&= -(3/n+O(1/n^2))-2+O(\ln(n)/n)\\
&= -2+O(\ln(n)/n)\\
&\to -2\\
\end{array}
$

so
$a_n \to e^{-2}
$.

$P(error) > .27$.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it as

$$a_n = \sqrt[n]{\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1-\frac{2}{j+2} \right)^{j+2}} $$

As this is of the form $\sqrt[n]{\prod_{j=1}^n c_j}$, you have

$$
\lim_n a_n = \lim_j c_j = e^{-2}
$$

Comment: Much simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

By setting $a_n = \log\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^n$ for any $n\geq 3$ we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n=-2.$
By Cesàro theorem (convergence implies convergence in average to the same limit) we have
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_3+a_4+\ldots+a_{n+2}}{n} = -2$$
and by exponentiating both sides
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{n}}\cdots\left(1-\frac{2}{n+2}\right)^{\frac{n+2}{n}} =\color{red}{e^{-2}}.$$